# Calling C nested function pointer from Lua

Tags: c, pointers, lua, ffi

I have the following C struct, that contains function pointer:

```
struct db {
    struct db_impl *impl;
    void (*test)(struct db *self); // How to invoke it from Lua??
};
void (*db_test)(void); // this I can invoke from Lua

struct db * get_db() {
    // create and init db
    struct db * db = init ...
    db->test = &db_real_impl; // db_real_impl is some C function
    return db;
}
```

So the test function pointer after initialization points to some function.
Now I need to call that function from Lua using FFI library, but it fails with error: `'void' is not callable`.

```
local db = ffi.C.get_db()
db.test(db)  -- fails to invoke
-- Error message: 'void' is not callable

ffi.C.db_test()  -- this works fine
```

In C the code would be:

```
struct db *db = get_db();
db->test(db);
```

In Lua I'm able to invoke free function pointers easily, but can't invoke function pointer from struct. How to invoke it from Lua?

Comment: `void (*db_test)(void);` wrong prototype, should be `void (*db_test)(struct db *);`

Comment: no, it's not wrong. db_test is different function pointer, it does not have any args. It's not relevant to the question anyway

Comment: Ah, then why are you showing this one?

Comment: Just to show that I can easily call *free* function pointers, but not the nested one (that belongs to struct)

Comment: Are you assigning some function to `test` before calling it? `db.test = somefunction`

Comment: It's C code that assigns some function to the function pointer, in the get_db() function. I'll update my post to clarify this

Comment: Sounds like a luajit ffi bug. please report at https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution seems to be pointed out in :
http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2015-07/msg00172.html

```
ffi.cdef[[
    typedef void (*test)(struct db *);
]]

local db = get_db()
local call = ffi.cast("test", db.test)
call(db)
```